Intermittent low voltage USB-C Power Delivery 12V adapter to PC fans
I'm using USB-C PD adapters like the ones pictured below connected to a USB Powerbank and then onwards to a power 1 or 2 Sickleflow 120mm PC fans.
Sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't (it's really obvious from the sound of the fans if they're receiving 12V or 5V).
At first I thought I just got some dud adapters (they're cheap ones off AliExpress), and was about to throw some of them out, but then I swapped things around a bit just out of interest and am seeing weird patterns like Adaptor A gives 12V work with Power Bank 1 but 5V with Power Bank 2, while Adaptor B gives 5 V work with Battery 1 but 12V with Power Bank 2, which makes me wonder if I'm missing something?
The combined current needed by the two fans is only 0.3amps (and rated safety current is .72amps) which is well within the specs for the power banks.
As a novice electrical engineer I'm having trouble figuring out if this is faulty equipment, or there's something I'm not understanding about USB-C PD and converting to 12V to supply PC fans.


If the only question is if you should stop buying from Aliexpress, I think you already know the answer based on how well those items work for you. USB is a standard so everything should work well together according to the specifications. But is there an electrical engineering question to this problem? It may depend on your power bank as well - if the plug wants to negotiate something that is not available, like 12V 3A, then it can't get it. What do your power banks support?

That wasn't my only question - the question is "is there something, as a novice electrical engineer, that I don't understand about USB-C PD?"
Because the pattern seems too consistent to be faulty equipment.

If the power banks communicate fine with mobile phone, then I'd blame the cheap adapters being non-compliant with the specs, but there is also a chance that all devices are compliant to the specs but they do things in a way that makes some work well together and some poorly. You can monitor the CC line for possible problems in the negotiation.


is there something [...] that I don't understand about USB-C PD?

Not directly, but indirectly. What you may not understand is that the level of understanding of USB-C PD among the product designers varies a lot. There is just a lot of very poorly implemented PD solutions out there.

the pattern seems too consistent to be faulty equipment

That's because you not-entirely-unreasonably assume that the equipment is faulty due to a random failure, rather than due to a systematic issue that was designed into it. It's the latter that you're facing.
Whether it's the issue with the plugs, the power banks, or both is hard to tell without using a PD analyzer to see what's going on and to verify whether the implementations on both ends are compliant with the specs. I can almost guarantee that there's plenty of deviation from the spec in the mix of the devices you're using.
These problems are so widespread that some hardware manufacturers actively work around them so that their device is not blamed for poor USB PD implementation on the other end of the cable. Some mobile devices go to extreme lengths to interoperate with non-compliant power sources when it's safe to do so. This is to the point of having firmware workarounds for ill-applied and/or ill-designed "PD chips" in widespread use, where some application circuit error got propagated to tens of millions of PCBs that then all misbehave in the same way.
If you think it's a bit of a stretch, let's go back a few decades. Observe how the most common mains-powered, mains-synchronized, 9V battery-backed clock chips from that era all run consistently way too fast when the mains synchronization is lost. A "close but no dice" value made its way onto an application circuit somehow, and propagated from there. Thus the oscillators free-run way too fast than what would be reasonable.
